Aggregate vs Populate methods when to use one in nodejs Mongose
I am creating asset managment tool for warehouse and I have Warehouse , Asset, Category models. I want to get the overall stats of each warehouse like , total assets and how many of them is active or in-store, so that I used aggregate but It seams to me more time consuming .
My question is what if I use populate method over aggregate, I mean store the needed asset values in the warehouse model or is there any better option for this
This is how I got the status of assets in on warehouse
const assetStats = await Asset.aggregate([
   {
     $group: {
       _id: id,
       totalAssets: { $sum: 1 },
       inStore: {
         $sum: {
           $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "in-store"] }, 1, 0],
         },
       },
       deployed: {
         $sum: {
           $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "deployed"] }, 1, 0],
         },
       },
       inRepair: {
         $sum: {
           $cond: [{ $eq: ["$status", "in-repair"] }, 1, 0],
         },
       },
     },
   },
]);


In your example , the aggregate function is required because you will aggregate your data to have the desired result .
The populate function mainly will do the population which is something like Inner JOIN in SQL requests .
